# Displaying PHP variable output

Tags: php

I've noticed that when I try to display the value of a variable with PHP, for example using print_r($array)/var_dump(), etc or even when using the Reflection API, I end up with output that is hard to read because there are no line breaks.  Every screen shot I see everywhere else has these things displayed in a sort of tree looking format that is much easier to read.  Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Ever heard of the thing called "HTML"?

Comment: What for? This is not a cliff-jumping site, if you didn't notice.

Comment: I've found that, when testing the functionality non-HTTP integrated components/data structures, merely to ensure they are holding the right data (*via `var_dump()`, etc.*) I just drop down to CLI. This obviously doesn't always apply, but I find myself very often command lining PHP scripts several times before I even open a browser (*again, given we're dealing with non-HTTP integrated functionality, where the CLI SAPI would not cause failure*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
echo nl2br($output);
```

Or try viewing it with the "View source" option of your browser.

Hope this helps

**EDIT**

OR just use the **pre** tags, like this:

```
<?php
function my_print_r($var) {
    $output = "";
    $output .= "<pre>";
    $output .= print_r($var, true);
    $output .= "</pre>";
    return $output;
}


echo my_print_r(array(1, 2, 3));
?>
```

Comment: The <pre> tags do it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a native feature of Php. Try installing [X-Debug](http://xdebug.org/index.php) for a better look and feel of your var_dump.

Answer (score 2):

If you would view it in a browser you could wrap it inside the `<pre>` HTML tag like so:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `echo '<pre>';` before printing the variable